# Error while using exit(0) in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var inDoubleTap = false; // Shared across all bound elements
return $list.live('touchstart', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.touches.length === 1) {
        if (!inDoubleTap) {
            inDoubleTap = true;
            setTimeout(function() { inDoubleTap = false }, delay);
        } else {
            inDoubleTap = false;
            callback.call(this, e);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
});
```

The above code shows an error if i use exit(0) in mobile browsers (iphone, ipad)

Comment: Under no circumstance tell us *what* error you're getting exactly - it would spoil the fun of guessing!

Comment: What did you expect `exit(0)` to do? Close the browser? Seriously, I'd like to understand your reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

Surely you mean `return;` instead of `exit(0)`. That should work.

Comment: I think they'd actually want `e.preventDefault();return false;` -- it *looks* like they're trying to cancel the event.